# Handle slicing and formatting strings with regex and Vue

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I have an issue when code vue, with string:

```
しらべよう、まとめよう　≪A≫[B]きものの　≪C≫[D]≪E≫[F]
```

I need processing to be able to render something like this:

the text above will be the text inside [].
then the bottom will start with the letter inside ≪≫, and finally the remaining letter.

```
...(if have)
 <ruby>B
   <rt>A</rt>
 </ruby>
... (if have)
<ruby>D
 <rt>C</rt>
</ruby>
... (if have)
```

https://codepen.io/AkiraGosho/pen/NWaNNrZ?editors=1111

This is my demo, but I only got 1 letter, so I don't know how to satisfy the problem

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `.replace`, here is an example:

```js
const input = 'しらべよう、まとめよう　≪A≫[B]きものの　≪C≫[D]≪E≫[F]'
const output = input.replace(/([^≪]*)≪(.)≫[^\[]*\[(.)\]/g, '$1\n<ruby>$3\n\t<rt>$2</rt>\n</ruby>\n');
console.log(output);
```

What this does, is to use a regex that splits the input into groups, the first group `([^≪]*)` selects any character that is not a `≪` fallowed by `≪`, then, the second group `(.)` selects a character preceded by `≪` and fallowed by `≫`. The third group uses the same logic but instead of using `≪` and `≫`, it uses `[` and `]`.

Comment: great, thank you so much
but there will be a case if there is more than 1 character in [] or <<>>, will it get it, how will I handle it in this case?

Comment: @CngtyCphnTponSovico It won't because I've used `(.)` which only matches one character. To do that, you can replace `(.)` with `([^≫]+)` for the first case and `([^\]]+)` for the second.